# Install - how to create additional partition (currently: 'unusable space')

Tags: partitioning

How can I create another partition (to e.g. parallel install a different ubuntu version) with this current partitioning table (`gparted` within Ubuntu install)? After shrinking `/dev/sda4` there is only this `'unusable'` space?!
My current partitions are as per gparted:

```
/dev/sda
   /dev/sda1 ntfs                (Windows)
   /dev/sda2 ntfs                (Windows)
   /dev/sda5 ext4                (Ubuntu /home)
   /dev/sda7 ntfs                (joint data partition)
   /dev/sda6 swap
   /dev/sda4 ext4   50028 MB     (Ubuntu 11.10)
   unusable         67000 MB
```

Any advice?
Could I create `/dev/sdb`, and if so, how?

## Update:

Actually using gparted (but not within the Ubuntu installation) shows this as

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
   /dev/sda5
   /dev/sda7
   /dev/sda6
/dev/sda4
unallocated
```

i.e. there are already 4 primary partitions.
Therefore: Is there a way of making `/dev/sda4` into an extended partition to create the logical `/dev/sda8` and `/dev/sda9` within? Or could I squeeze a `/dev/sda8` after `/dev/sda6` if I shrink `/dev/sda6`?

## Solved

I reexpanded `sda4` to its previous size, shrunk `sda5`, and was able to create an `sda8` as part of `sda3`.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem but I don't really understand your solution. I have two windows install (7/8 -- NTFS) and am installing Ubuntu (12.04) as well. When I make a /boot partition for Ubuntu the rest of the space is left unusable. Any chance you remember more specifics? Current solution is a bit vague and tied to the partition numbers which I can't seem to follow. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see question `update` and `solved` part. (ultimately more an issue with the gparted display within the ubuntu installation, which made it difficult to realise the 4 partition layout.)

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously try to create the new partition using `gparted`, but it is not possible to be `/dev/sdb`. All those `sda` meant that they are on a same physical hard drive. The number behind shows their partition. Usually gparted will automatically assign a name for your device  based on the position of your partition within the hard drive, such as `/dev/sda3`.

UPDATE:
There can only be only one `extended partition` in one physical hard disk. As you already have `/dev/sda3` as an extended partition, it is not possible to convert `/dev/sda4` into an extended partition. The position of your unallocated data does not allow you to create any new partition unless you reduce the primary partition into 3.

I have read about cases where you can merge your '/dev/sda4' into the `/dev/sda3` as a logical partition inside the extended partition and make your total number of primary partitions into 3 but I do not know how to do that myself.